# "To" with transitive verbs

Tags: questions, transitive-verbs

Which sentence sounds better:

"Who is she speaking to?"

or

"To whom is she speaking?".

As I see, the both are grammatically correct, whereas books have the former example and in speech I notice the latter.

Comment: I would say/write "Who is she speaking to?" pretty much all of the time. The only exception would be if you're wanting to make a point of sounding pompous/old-fashioned for effect – then you could say "To whom is she speaking?".

Comment: Also, when speaking most people would probably contract *who is* and say "Who's she speaking to?"